# how to share a scope variable with ng-app's in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I have two different ng-app running on same page.

1. bookingApp
2. calendarApp

I want to share selected date scope variable from calendarApp to bookingApp.
How I can achieve this functionality?

Thanks,
Gladiator

Comment: do you want to say angular modules or `ng-app`s?

Comment: clearly mentioned ng-apps

Answer (score 1):

You have to use angularjs service for this purpose.Hope the following implementation will help you to get some understanding

```
angular.module('app.A', [])
.service('ServiceA', function() {
    this.getValue = function() {
        return this.myValue;
    };

    this.setValue = function(newValue) {
        this.myValue = newValue;
    }
});

angular.module('app.B', ['app.A'])
.service('ServiceB', function(ServiceA) {
    this.getValue = function() {
        return ServiceA.getValue();
    };

    this.setValue = function() {
        ServiceA.setValue('New value');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Dev, I am getting null value when I access the share variable from app.B

Comment: Are you injecting services properly ?? can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between Angular apps by [Window postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and / or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

Just wrap **postMessave** into Angular Service and propagate changes on post event.